# C# tidy way to set long list of class values?

Tags: c#, coding-style, refactoring

I have a class with 60 different strings in it. I need to fetch the strings from an API where they have one name, save them and then insert them into to a database where they have another name.

So my code is currently 60 lines of code that looks like this

```
var data = (from l in resultsxml.Root.Descendants(ns + "contacts").Elements(ns + "contact")
select new contact {
id                              = (string)l.Element("id").Value,
surname                         = (string)l.Element("lastName").Value,
companyName                     = (string)l.Element("organisationName").Value,
...
```

and then another 60 lines like this

```
cmd.Parameters(new SqlParameter("@LastName", i.surname));
cmd.Parameters(new SqlParameter("@DivisionName", i.companyName));
...
```

As well as the class declaration.

Is there a tidier way to write this so I can loop through the 60 strings and store the name information in the class?

Comment: Wouldn't it be good to pass an `Xml` itself as a parameter and perform mapping(logic) in the database?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an attribute class:

```
public class ElementAndParamNameAttribute : Attribute
{
  public string Element {get;set;}
  public string Param {get;set;}
}
.
.
.
public class contact
{
   [ElementAndParamNameAttribute(Element="lastName",Param="@lastName")]
   public string surname {get;set;}
   .
   .
   .
}
```

And then loop through the properties of `contact` using `typeof(contact).GetProperties()`, find the attribute using `PropertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes()`, set the value using `PropertyInfo.GetValue()` then get the value using `PropertyInfo.SetValue()`.

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of properties. Maybe you can split up your class in smaller ones? Like "Name" and "Address" or something (I can't see them all so I don't know if it makes sense).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31823237)